# How to extract double from string in dart?

Tags: dart

I have a string containing 3 or 4 double numbers. what's the best way to extract them in an array of numbers?

Comment: Please post the string. There are many ways how 3 or 4 double numbers can be contained in a string.

Comment: it might be like"Points (64.5464864, 34.668464)" I'm not just looking for a way for a special data. it will be so good if it was a more generic way;

Answer (score 6):

First you have to find the numerals. You can use a `RegExp` pattern for that, say:

```
var doubleRE = RegExp(r"-?(?:\d*\.)?\d+(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?");
```

Then you parse the resulting strings with `double.parse`. Something like:

```
var numbers = doubleRE.allMatches(input).map((m) => double.parse(m[0])).toList();
```